# QPdfWriter and page size

Tags: c++, qt, pdf

I'm setting page size to `QPdfWriter`, but it seems like requested size is applied only to pages created with `newPage()`, which doesn't apply for the first page. Is there a way to change size of the first page, or is it a bug in Qt?

Qt version: 5.2.1.

Here's small code snippet to reproduce the problem:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFile f("/tmp/test.pdf");
    f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QPdfWriter* writer = new QPdfWriter(&f);
    QPainter* p = new QPainter(writer);
    writer->setPageSize(QPagedPaintDevice::A5);
    p->drawText(QRect(100, 100, 2000, 200), "test");
    writer->newPage();
    p->drawText(QRect(100, 100, 2000, 200), "test");
    delete p;
    delete writer;
    f.close();
}
```

Created PDF file has first page in A4 format and second in A5 format, but they should both be in A5 format.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `setPageSize` before `new QPainter`. 
Following works for me:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFile f("/tmp/test.pdf");
    f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QPdfWriter* writer = new QPdfWriter(&f);
    // -- begin of change
    writer->setPageSize(QPagedPaintDevice::A5);
    QPainter* p = new QPainter(writer);
    // -- end of change
    p->drawText(QRect(100, 100, 2000, 200), "test");
    writer->newPage();
    p->drawText(QRect(100, 100, 2000, 200), "test");
    delete p;
    delete writer;
    f.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Qt 5.2.1. I've just tried 5.3.0 and it works correctly.